# Using MacBook with a broken screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, hdmi

About a year ago me and my friend found a MacBook in the road. The screen is destroyed, but everything else was fine. We plugged in an HDMI adapter and were able to get a name off of the MacBook log in screen, so we contacted the owner off Instagram. She told us she had already replaced the laptop and that we were welcome to keep it if we could find use for it. Because of this we decided it would be a good idea to reset the laptop entirely. Unfortunately, we didn’t realize Mac software has a feature where HDMI can’t display the screen until you are fully booted into the laptop. Since it is currently in setup mode after the factory reset, we can’t get it to display on HDMI. We had long given up, but now my personal laptop is having some issues, and I want to try to use the MacBook. How can I get this set up?